# How to show two objects in one cell (tableView)?

Tags: iphone, ios, cell, tableview

I ran into a small problem. I created a `UITableView` where the user can add his contacts from his addressbook. The firstName gets displayed in the first row, the lastName in the second one. I know where the problem is, because right now I actually tell him how to do that.
But how can I tell him to display both names in the same cell? I did it with the following methods but they don't work.

```
-(void)addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray
{
     NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [myArray addObjectsFromArray:menuArray];
     NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The problem is that I cannot display objects from myArray because `cellforRowAtIndex` method does not get the value. And with that one I get the same result (firstName first Row, lastName second Row):

```
NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstName, lastName, nil];
NSString *cellValue = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
NSLog(@"%@", objects);

return cell;
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what does `addObjectsFromArray` do? Your code seems a little confusing. Then, I suggest you to read the following tutorial on [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Well I dont implement both of the codes, I just tried it with both of them. And I add two objects two one array and then add that array to another array. I had hoped that this way it would display both objects in one cell.

Comment: ok, so what do you want to know? do you want to have suggestions on how to implement the above mechanism? Maybe you could try to reformulate your question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well I just want to get the firstName and lastName to be displayed in one row :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only does your code display the first name and last name in different cells, it also does not work for rows at indexes greater than one. This is because your table data source reads from a brand-new array that you create with alloc/init on the first line, rather than reading from your *model*. Your little array contains only two objects, explaining the two rows.

Here is what you need to do: first, make an array of users available to your table's data source. Suppose it's called `userArray`. Put user data for each user into that array. Suppose each user is stored as an object of type `MYUser` that responds to `[user firstName]` and `[user lastName]` calls with the first and the last name of the user.

Now put this code into your table's data source:

```
MYUser *user = [userArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [user firstName], [user lastName]];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

**EDIT** : If your `menuArray` stores the first and the last names in separate consecutive string objects, you can still do it (though I recommend against it, because it will be confusing to people who maintain your program in the future).

First, you need to change the method that returns the number of items in the table to return `menuArray.count / 2` instead of just `menuArray.count`. Then you can modify your code as follows:

```
NSString firstName = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2];
NSString lastName = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row/2 + 1];
NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
```

**EDIT2** : Here is how you create a class that stores the first and the last name of a user. You add the `@interface` part to `MYUser.h`, and the `@implementation` part to `MYUser.m` file. You then import `MYUser.h` in .m files from which you reference `MYUser` class, and use `initWithFirstName:andLastName:` to initialize new instances. The sample below assumes that you use ARC:

MYUser.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MYUser : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;
-(id)initWithFirstName:(NSString*)first andLastName:(NSString*)last;
@end
```

MYUser.m file:

```
@implementation MYUser
@synthesize firstName, lastName;
-(id)initWithFirstName:(NSString*)first andLastName:(NSString*)last {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.firstName = first;
        self.lastName = last;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the elaborate explanation. But could you tell me what you mean to store a user as an object of type MYUser?

Comment: @Blade The `firstName` and `lastName` variables in your second code snippet come from some object; I do not know its type, so I labeled it `MYUser`.

Comment: So I added firstName and lastName to the array menuArray. So the users are stored in this array. But how can I store them again in another object?

Comment: @Blade Does your menuArray contain the first and the last names in separate strings then, like `{"Joe", "Smith", "Peter", "Paulson", nil}`? You can make the models like this work, too, but it may make things difficult to understand. I'll update the answer shortly to show you how to do it, but doing it like that will confuse the readers of your program.

Comment: Hey, I marked it as the right answer, thanks again. It works like this, but I understand what you mean, it is kinda confusing. Would it be too much to ask if you could explain me your first solution? I kinda don't get how to add the variables to another object :(

Comment: @Blade Sure, I just added a very simple implementation of `MYUser` that you could use as a starting point for developing a user class for your model.

Comment: It seems to work, except when I run it and try to add someone I get a SIGABRT error at this line 
NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [user firstName], [user lastName]];   I use ARC btw

Comment: @Blade Stop at that line in the debugger, and see if you get the correct object from your array.

Comment: Yes I get the correct object. NSZombie says: "NSInvalidArguemntException", reason '-[_NSCFString firstName]:unrecognized selector sent to instance." Which is weird, because firstName is definitely nil.

Comment: @Blade This is because you put `NSString` objects into your array instead of `MYUser` objects. In the method that populates `menuArray`, change the code to call `[[MYUser alloc] initWithFirstName:firstName andLastName:lastName]`, and put the result into `menuArray`.

Comment: So basically where I do this  [menuArray addObject:firstName]; 
    [menuArray addObject:lastName]; I do [[Contacts alloc] initWithFirstName:firstName andLastName:lastName] ? How do I put the result then in my array? I obviously cant use contacts :)

Comment: @Blade you do this: `[menuArray addObject:[[MYUser alloc] initWithFirstName:firstName andLastName:lastName]];`

Comment: Thanks it works, he only displays the firstname though, also he has the lastname saved aswell. Weird. But I think I will find the error :)